# How to use a relative path in a parent folder in electron app?

Tags: javascript, html, directory, electron

How do I use a relative path without specifying a specific drive in my electron app? I need to use something like `SRC="/FILE.HTML"` so my app will work on any drive installed not just a specific location. I know `./` and `../` go to previous parent folders but how can I go a few more directories back? I've seen things like `%appdir%/MAIN DIR/SUB DIR/FILE.HTML`, however I'm not sure how that works? Maybe I can setup some kind of variable to use in my path like that? So far I've only been able to use direct paths to go to files in previous folder which constricts my software to a specific drive.

Example: `MAIN DIR`/`SUB DIR`/`FILE.HTML`

EDIT: My electron app isnt displaying my Main.html. I think it has to do with my paths but im not sure?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Maybe I can keep using ../../../FILE.HTML? To keep going back DIRs

Comment: PS: Next time, use code blocks with your question instead of images of code. It takes ages for us to type an answer instead of just copying / pasting your code and the relevant fix...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using absolute paths will cause you issues, especially during / after build process. Your Electron application would be
built referencing files in the wrong directories. Relevant file reference is the way to go here.

> IMPORTANT: I am seeing a lot of inconsistent directory naming and file references in your directory structure.
> EG: `Main.html` is in your `JAVASCRIPT` directory. `Main.js` (not your application entry point) is not shown in your
> directory structure. Same for your `Index.css` file. As a result, answering this question accurately is difficult due
> to the many "norms" usually found in project structure and naming conventions. Comment to this answer fir more information / help.

---

Within your `package.json` file, the `"main": "..."` line is the entry point to your application. As this is
relative to your project root and your `Main.js` file is at your project root, your entry point will be `"Main.js"`

> PS: `"electron"` doesn't need to be a dependency, only a devDependency.

`package.json` (project root)

```json
{
    "name": "electron.menu",
    "version": "00.00.01",
    "description": "Electron Menu Portable Start Menu",
    "main": "Main.js"
    "scripts": {
        "start": "electron .",
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    },
    "keywords": [],
    "author": "Armored Security Group",
    "license": "MIT",
    "devDependencies": {
        "electron": "^19.0.6"
    }
}
```

---

Within your `Main.js` file, the path to your `index.html` file, or in your case, your `Main.html` file, is again,
relative (this time to the `Main.js` file as this is the file requiring it).

Using Node's [`path.join([...path]);`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest/docs/api/path.html#pathjoinpaths) method (as you
have) will place you in good stead.

> Note the use
> of [`win.loadFile(...)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadfilefilepath-options) instead
> of [`win.loadURL(...)`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window#winloadurlurl-options)

`Main.js` (main process)

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

let win

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    });
    
    win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'ROOT.ASSETS/CODE.FILES/JAVASCRIPT/Main.html'));
    
    return win;
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    win = createWindow();
});
```

---

Lastly, within your `Main.html` file, all paths will be relevant to the file itself. IE: `Main.html`.

That said, I don't see `Main.js` within your `ROOT.ASSETS/CODE.FILES/JAVASCRIPT` directory.

Additionally, I don't see `Index.css` within your `ROOT.ASSETS/CODE.FILES/` **STYLESHEET** `/INDEX.STYLE` directory.

> PS: Place your Javascript file(s) after the closing tag of your `</body>` element. That way, you do not need
> to `defer`
> and your script(s) will always have a full DOM to work with (unless you need to make an update to your DOM before the
> page is rendered).

`ROOT.ASSETS/CODE.FILES/JAVASCRIPT/Main.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../STYLESHEET/INDEX.STYLE/Index.css" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
    
    <script src="/Main.js"></script>
</html>
```

---

> PS: One final note, there is no real need to have directory names or file name use upper case unless you are using
> camelCase.

---

## Update

### Relative & Absolute Paths

Path reference is different between file systems and internet URL's

#### File Systems

For our file systems example we will use:

```
D:/
└── path
    └── to
        └── my
            ├── first
            |   └── file.txt
            └── second
                └── file.txt
```

##### Absolute Paths

Absolute paths are paths that refer to the **whole** file path. They are **absolute**.

```
D:/path/to/my/first/file.txt
D:/path/to/my/second/file.txt
```

Let's say are are somewhere in the `D:/` drive. You could be anywhere.

To get to your "first" file you would use ***the full path*** to the first text file.

```
D:/path/to/my/first/file.txt
```

Alternatively, you could use

```
/path/to/my/first/file.txt
```

This will take you to the same location if you are already in the `D:/` drive. If you are in another drive, it will take you to the **absolute path** in that drive instead.

To get to your "second" file you would use ***the full path*** to the second text file.

```
D:/path/to/my/second/file.txt
```

or

```
/path/to/my/second/file.txt
```

##### Relative Paths

Relative paths are paths that refer to a **point in the file system from another point in the file system**.

Let's say we open a console starting at the `D:/` directory. IE: The **root** of the `D:/` drive.

```
D:/
```

To get to your "first" file you would use **the path** to the first text file. The reference will always start from the **current directory**. In this case, it happens to be the **root** of the `D:/` drive.

```
path/to/my/first/text.file
```

From here, to get to your "second" file, you will need to move up one directory level `../`, which will take you to `path/to/my`. From here you then need to move down into the `second` directory to the second text file.

```
../second/file.txt
```

If you want to go to the root of the drive that you are currently in (without worrying about what drive you are in) use `/`.

```
/
```

This will take you back to:

```
D:/
```

Linux also has `./` which is used to reference a relative path.

#### Internet URL's

Similar to file systems, but used when referencing URL addresses.

For our Internet URL's example we will use:

```
www.example.com
└── path
    └── to
        └── my
            ├── cool
            |   └── page.html
            └── other-cool
                └── page.html
```

##### Absolute URL

```
https://www.example.com/path/to/my/cool/page.html
```

##### Relative URL

Let's navigate to another page without using the absolute URL to the other page.

```
../other-cool/page.html
```

As we are already in the `cool` path, this takes us up one level to `my` and back down through `other-cool` to `page.html`.

IE:

```
https://www.example.com/path/to/my/other-cool/page.html
```

To move up two levels from here, would would use

```
../../
```

Which would take us to

```
https://www.example.com/path/to
```

---

### Typical Electron Folder Structure

After we finish coding our Electron application, we "build" it. Our newly "built" code must be placed in a different directory to that of our "source" code else we would overwrite our source code.

Thus we will use the `dist` and `src` names as folder names.

- `dist` holds our distributable code. EG `myApp.exe`
- `src` holds our source code.

`build` is often used as an intermediary to hold specific OS architecture output during the build process.

```
Project Root
├── build
├── dist
├── node_modules
├── src
├── tests
├── .gitignore
├── package.json
└── package-lock.json
```

As a personal preference, I then split my `src` folder into directories / files like below.

```
src
├── main-process
|   ├── dialogs
|   ├── localization
|   ├── menus
|   |   ├── main-menu.js
|   |   └── tray-menu.js
|   ├── preferences
|   ├── windows
|   |   └── main-window.js
|   ├── main.js
|   └── preload.js
├── render-process
|   ├── css
|   |   └── index.css
|   ├── html
|   |   └── index.html
|   ├── images
|   └── js
|       └── index.js
└── config.json
```

Therefore, a basic `package.json` file would refer to your main entry file `main.js` like this.

`package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "myApp",
  "productName": "My cool application",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "src/main-process/main.js"
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "",
    "start": "electron .",
    "lint": "",
    "unit-test": ",
    "clean": "",
    "bundle-win": "electron-packager ./ server-x --overwrite --out=build/bundles --platform=win32 --arch=all --prune=true --asar --icon='./src/render-process/images/icons/icon.png'",
    "dist-win": "electron-builder --windows ",
    "release": ""
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "electron": "^19.0.0",
    "electron-builder": "^23.0.0",
    "electron-packager": "^15.0.0"
  }
}
```

Your `main.js` file would look like this.

`main.js` (main process)

```js
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron');
const url = require('url');
const path = require('path');

let win

function createWindow() {
    win = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 800,
        height: 600
    });
    
    win.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, '../render-process/html/index.html'));
    
    return win;
}

app.on('ready', () => {
    win = createWindow();
});
```

And finally, your `index.html` file would look like this.

`index.html` (render process)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-us">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Electron Menu</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/index.css" />
    </head>
    
    <body>
        ...
    </body>
    
    <script src="../js/index.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: I had moved my main to my base dir for a minute seeing if my paths were the problem and even then, all in the same folder with wasn't working. Then I reverted it back and ig put the wrong main in the wrong folder before I took the screenshot. It wasn't swapped like that before. And it wasn't working.

Comment: The way I write my initial html with redundant is more or less a placeholder for future development. it's like a basic template i have in my mind.

Comment: I think i see how placing main in the base dir will help with relativity of paths as well. Does it have to be in the base dir?

Comment: I've gotten pretty good with nwjs but it lacks features so I thought I'd start learning electron. Very confusing learning curve.

Comment: I'm still so confused with the relative paths. Like i have portable software installed in another folder in the same dir as the project folder that i will have to execute from my app so I'm not sure how to use a relative path backwards to get to those folders.

Comment: Its so hard to word all this correctly in just text. My folder structure is rather complex. Its like portableapps.com. My main app is eventually a start menu. There is multiple apps such as calculators and text editors that will be packaged with it so I can't have everything under the same directory.  It is almost like a portable operating system.

Comment: https://github.com/ArmoredSecGroup/Secure-Menu-BETA here is my nwjs one I was making but i want to rebuild it. I dont like how i did some designing of things with it. It will only work if installed on D:

Comment: @DustinAngeletti "Does it have to be in the base dir?" No, it doesn't. It can be anywhere you like but there are some norms you can follow that sort of standardise your code so other can read and understand it quickly and easily. Electron can be confusing at the start, especially IPC. I will append my answer with some relative / absolute path info and a typical Electron folder structure.